# Input has quotes automatically added

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent-storage

I'm using Yesod to write a personal backup system, and running into an interesting issue. I'm relatively inexperienced when it comes to Haskell so I'm sure none of this is optimal.

Here is one of my handlers:

```
postHostR :: Text -> RcPath -> Handler Text
postHostR hostName f = do
  hostId <- insertIfDontExist hostName
  tBody <- (T.pack . show) <$> getRawRequest
  time <- lift getCurrentTime
  newId <- runDB $ insert $ RcFile hostId tBody (makePath f) time
  return $ T.pack $ show newId
```

Any of the text I retrieve from the DB has double quotes automatically added. I'm assuming this is some kind of XSS security but I'm not concerned about that since I'm not going to be rendering pages. The quotes don't seem to be actually part of the text (I've tried just stripping the first and last character, but that doesn't seem to actually remove the quotes).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing one of those `show` calls is to blame, but I'm not familiar with the packages involved. What types is `show` used at? You can find out by changing each call to `(show :: _)` and looking at the errors.

Comment: Almost definitely `newId` is either `Text` or `String`. Note that `show "abc" == "\"abc\""`

Comment: Sure enough, you're both right. I was doing `show` on something of type `Text`, I guess the proper thing to do is use `unpack` to get a real string out of it. Can one of you please answer the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual cause of this problem is that you have a string and you've called `show` on it when you didn't need to. (Most typically somebody does `print x` when they really wanted `putStrLn x`.)

In your case, I'm unsure of the type signatures, but I *suspect* that your final line can be changed from

```
return $ T.pack $ show newId
```

to just

```
return newId
```

I suspect `newId` is *already* `Text`, so calling `show` on it just puts unwanted quotes around it (and turns it into a `String`, which you then use `T.pack` to turn back into `Text`). If you just return it, it'll probably work.

(Then again, I could be completely mistaken about the type signature; it's hard to tell from here.)

Comment: In my case I was using `show` on `Text` in place of what I now know should be `unpack`. Your answer still holds. Thanks.